# completely transparent status bar and navigation bar on lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm trying to make an android launcher. I want to achieve a completely transparent status bar and navigation bar, here is my theme xml file.

```
<resources>
    <style name="Theme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">false</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

the last two items don't work, there is still a shadow on lollipop.

This is what it looks like(note there is actually a shadow on status bar and navigation bar):
[image]

what I want to achieve (nova launcher):

[image]

how to make the status bar and navigation bar "transparent" instead of "translucent"?

Answer (score 163):

### Update

You can achieve the same effect programmatically on KitKat and afterward by setting the `FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS` flag inside the `Window`.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            Window w = getWindow(); // in Activity's onCreate() for instance
            w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
        }
```

If you set a background resource (*like a color or a picture*) to your layout, you will see the color or picture "below" the status bar.

```
<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/primary_dark</item>
```

---

### Original Answer

It looks like `android:windowTranslucentStatus` and `android:windowTranslucentNavigation` should be `true` instead of `false`

```
<resources>
    <style name="Theme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Also, your transparent activity / container layout needs this property set:

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

[Source][1]
[1]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29311321/1549700

Comment: Note that I didn't need the theme part, the java code was enough.

Comment: I have a webview based app. It crashes with W/OpenGLRenderer: Layer exceeds max. dimensions supported by the GPU (1920x19968, max=4096x4096) when I set `FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS` flag on Android 6.

Comment: This answer is not good for apps that use a bottom navigation bar because it loses the limits and drops the navigation bottom bar down to the phone soft keys.

Comment: @Machado Its working but using FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, its hide actionbar controls like after appling this navigation drawer event not working.

Comment: you may also need to set `<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/transparent</item>`  in your style.xml.

Comment: It is not working out side application in landscape mode

Comment: This crashes Snacbar appear behaviour, such a shame google didn't test everything he creates

Comment: How is this the correct answer? NO_LIMITS makes content drawn on both the status bar and navigation bar. The goal is to merely make the navigation bar fully transparent.

Comment: `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` doesn't work with NO_LIMITS, bad answer

Comment: my toolbar go hide after using this code

Comment: @yoavgray You can easily fix that by assigning a limit to how much a bottom nav drawer can be wrapped. Not really a big issue.

Comment: This breaks Flutter's SafeArea widget

Answer (score 15):

You can use this kotlin extension function it will set status bar fully transparent (on **API 23+**, `View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR` flag available on **API 23+**) and navigation bar (on **API 27+**, `View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_NAVIGATION_BAR` flag available on **API 27+**) otherwise it will use the `systemUiScrim` color on **API 21+**

```kotlin
fun Activity.transparentStatusAndNavigation(
    systemUiScrim: Int = Color.parseColor("#40000000") // 25% black
) {
    var systemUiVisibility = 0
    // Use a dark scrim by default since light status is API 23+
    var statusBarColor = systemUiScrim
    //  Use a dark scrim by default since light nav bar is API 27+
    var navigationBarColor = systemUiScrim
    val winParams = window.attributes


    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        systemUiVisibility = systemUiVisibility or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR
        statusBarColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        systemUiVisibility = systemUiVisibility or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_NAVIGATION_BAR
        navigationBarColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        systemUiVisibility = systemUiVisibility or
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE or
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN or
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
        window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = systemUiVisibility
    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        winParams.flags = winParams.flags or
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS or
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION
    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        winParams.flags = winParams.flags and
                (WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS or
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION).inv()
        window.statusBarColor = statusBarColor
        window.navigationBarColor = navigationBarColor
    }

    window.attributes = winParams
}
```

**API 21+**
[image: API 21+]
**API 27+**
[image: API 27+]

Answer (score 15):

For API 29 and above use

```
<style name="Your.Theme">
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:enforceNavigationBarContrast">false</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate why?

Answer (score 9):

I use this since it keeps the height of the status bar and nav bar

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="theme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">#00000000</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">#00000000</item>
</style>
```

This does require API 21+ however

Comment: doesn't work for me. What other attributes do you use with those?

Answer (score 4):

You need to add `android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds` flag to you theme

```
<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
```

Or call this in onCreate()

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
```

Comment: This does not make the navigation bar transparent.

Comment: @nhaarman You need to add this as well. Window w = getWindow(); w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);

Answer (score 4):

The following code is an example of what I use in my project:

styles.xml

```
<style name="FadingActionBarTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/FadingActionBarWidget</item>
</style>

<style name="FadingActionBarWidget.Transparent">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>

<style name="FadingActionBarTheme.TranslucentActionBar">
    <item name="android:icon">@drawable/ic_ab_icon</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/FadingActionBarWidget.Transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
    android:name=".MyActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/FadingActionBarTheme.TranslucentActionBar">
</activity>
```

Answer (score 4):

### **100% working code**

### Completely Transparent StatusBar and NavigationBar

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    initStatusNavBar();
    transparentStatusAndNavigation();

    showSystemUI();
    // hideSystemUI();

}

public static void transparentStatusAndNavigation(Activity activity) {

    Window window = activity.getWindow();

    // make full transparent statusBar
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
        setWindowFlag(window, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION, true);
    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
        int visibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN;
        visibility = visibility | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION;
        window.getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(visibility);
    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        int windowManager = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS;
        windowManager = windowManager | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION;
        setWindowFlag(window, windowManager, false);
        window.setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        window.setNavigationBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }

}

private static void setWindowFlag(final int bits, boolean on) {
    Window win = getWindow();
    WindowManager.LayoutParams winParams = win.getAttributes();
    if (on) {
        winParams.flags |= bits;
    } else {
        winParams.flags &= ~bits;
    }
    win.setAttributes(winParams);
}
```

### Set StatusBar & NavigationBar height & Color:

**in activity_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/status_bg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/primaryColorLightThemeDarkTrans"
        tools:layout_height="24dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <!--Write Code Here-->

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/nav_bg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/navColorLightThemeTrans"
        tools:layout_height="?actionBarSize" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**in java code:**

```
private void initStatusNavBar() {
    int statusBarHeight = getStatusBarHeight(activity);
    int navBarHeight = getNavigationBarHeight(activity, statusBarHeight);

    View statusBarBackground = findViewById(R.id.status_bg);
    statusBarBackground.getLayoutParams().height = statusBarHeight;

    View navBarBackground = findViewById(R.id.nav_bg);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        setNavigationBarHeight(activity, navBarBackground);
    } else {
        navBarBackground.getLayoutParams().height = navBarHeight;
    }
}

public static int getStatusBarHeight(Activity activity) {
    final Resources resources = activity.getResources();
    final int resId = resources.getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
    if (resId > 0) {
        return resources.getDimensionPixelSize(resId);
    }
    return 0;
}

public static int getNavigationBarHeight(Activity activity, int statusBarHeight) {
    Point point = getNavigationBarSize(activity);
    int height = point.y;
    if (isNotchDisplay(statusBarHeight)) {
        height = height - statusBarHeight;
    }
    return height;
}

private static Point getNavigationBarSize(Context context) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        Point appUsableSize = getAppUsableScreenSize(context);
        Point realScreenSize = getRealScreenSize(context);

        // navigation bar on the right
        if (appUsableSize.x < realScreenSize.x) {
            return new Point(realScreenSize.x - appUsableSize.x, appUsableSize.y);
        }

        // navigation bar at the bottom
        if (appUsableSize.y < realScreenSize.y) {
            return new Point(appUsableSize.x, realScreenSize.y - appUsableSize.y);
        }

        // navigation bar is not present
        return new Point();
    }
    return new Point();
}

private static Point getAppUsableScreenSize(Context context) {
    WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Point size = new Point();
    if (null != windowManager) {
        Display display = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
        display.getSize(size);
    }
    return size;
}

private static Point getRealScreenSize(Context context) {
    WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Point size = new Point();
    if (null != windowManager) {
        Display display = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
            display.getRealSize(size);
        } else {
            try {
                size.x = (Integer) Display.class.getMethod("getRawWidth").invoke(display);
                size.y = (Integer) Display.class.getMethod("getRawHeight").invoke(display);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    return size;
}

private static boolean isNotchDisplay(int statusBarHeight) {
    int normalStatusBarHeight = dpToPxForNav(25);
    return statusBarHeight > normalStatusBarHeight;
}

private static int dpToPxForNav(float dp) {
    DisplayMetrics metrics = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics();
    float px = dp * (metrics.densityDpi / 160f);
    return Math.round(px);
}

public static void setNavigationBarHeight(Activity activity, View navBarBackground) {
    ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(navBarBackground, (v, insets) -> {
        int navBarHeight = insets.getSystemWindowInsetBottom();
        navBarBackground.getLayoutParams().height = navBarHeight;
        return insets.consumeSystemWindowInsets();
    });
}


@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
public void showSystemUI() {
    statusBarBackground.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    navBarBackground.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mDecorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
public void hideSystemUI() {
    statusBarBackground.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    navBarBackground.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mDecorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // hide nav bar
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // hide status bar
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
}
```

### Theme at styles.xml:

```
<style name="MyAppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

    <!--For Notch Issues-->
    <item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode" tools:targetApi="o_mr1">shortEdges</item>

    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryColorDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accentColor</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorHighlight</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#fff6d7</item>

    <item name="android:colorPrimary" tools:targetApi="lollipop">@color/primaryColor</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark" tools:targetApi="lollipop">@color/primaryColorDark</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="lollipop">@color/primaryColorDark</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent" tools:targetApi="lollipop">@color/accentColorLight</item>
    <item name="android:colorControlHighlight" tools:targetApi="lollipop">@color/colorHighlight</item>

    <item name="android:navigationBarColor" tools:targetApi="lollipop">@color/navColor</item>

    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus" tools:targetApi="kitkat">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation" tools:targetApi="kitkat">true</item>

</style>
```

### in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.MyActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
        android:theme="@style/MyAppTheme" />
```

Comment: Not working on Pixel 2 XL with Android 9.

Also changing bottom software buttons bar to white bar without visible buttons.

Comment: @Potass you have to add flag `View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR` for `Api 23+`. Requests the status bar to draw in a mode that is compatible with light status bar backgrounds. For this to take effect, the window must request `FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS` but not `FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS`. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR play with the settings to get the desired effect.

Comment: maybe also you need add window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS)
or else your bars will black

Answer (score 1):

To draw your layout under statusbar :

values/styles.xml

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
```

values-v21/styles.xml

```
<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
```

Use CoordinatorLayout/DrawerLayout which already take care of the fitsSystemWindows parameter or create your own layout to  like this:

```
public class FitsSystemWindowConstraintLayout extends ConstraintLayout {

    private Drawable mStatusBarBackground;
    private boolean mDrawStatusBarBackground;

    private WindowInsetsCompat mLastInsets;

    private Map<View, int[]> childsMargins = new HashMap<>();

    public FitsSystemWindowConstraintLayout(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public FitsSystemWindowConstraintLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public FitsSystemWindowConstraintLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

        if (ViewCompat.getFitsSystemWindows(this)) {
            ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(this, new android.support.v4.view.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener() {
                @Override
                public WindowInsetsCompat onApplyWindowInsets(View view, WindowInsetsCompat insets) {
                    FitsSystemWindowConstraintLayout layout = (FitsSystemWindowConstraintLayout) view;
                    layout.setChildInsets(insets, insets.getSystemWindowInsetTop() > 0);
                    return insets.consumeSystemWindowInsets();
                }
            });
            setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
            TypedArray typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(new int[]{android.R.attr.colorPrimaryDark});
            try {
                mStatusBarBackground = typedArray.getDrawable(0);
            } finally {
                typedArray.recycle();
            }
        } else {
            mStatusBarBackground = null;
        }
    }

    public void setChildInsets(WindowInsetsCompat insets, boolean draw) {
        mLastInsets = insets;
        mDrawStatusBarBackground = draw;
        setWillNotDraw(!draw && getBackground() == null);

        for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
            View child = getChildAt(i);
            if (child.getVisibility() != GONE) {
                if (ViewCompat.getFitsSystemWindows(this)) {
                    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();

                    if (ViewCompat.getFitsSystemWindows(child)) {
                        ViewCompat.dispatchApplyWindowInsets(child, insets);
                    } else {
                        int[] childMargins = childsMargins.get(child);
                        if (childMargins == null) {
                            childMargins = new int[]{layoutParams.leftMargin, layoutParams.topMargin, layoutParams.rightMargin, layoutParams.bottomMargin};
                            childsMargins.put(child, childMargins);
                        }
                        if (layoutParams.leftToLeft == LayoutParams.PARENT_ID) {
                            layoutParams.leftMargin = childMargins[0] + insets.getSystemWindowInsetLeft();
                        }
                        if (layoutParams.topToTop == LayoutParams.PARENT_ID) {
                            layoutParams.topMargin = childMargins[1] + insets.getSystemWindowInsetTop();
                        }
                        if (layoutParams.rightToRight == LayoutParams.PARENT_ID) {
                            layoutParams.rightMargin = childMargins[2] + insets.getSystemWindowInsetRight();
                        }
                        if (layoutParams.bottomToBottom == LayoutParams.PARENT_ID) {
                            layoutParams.bottomMargin = childMargins[3] + insets.getSystemWindowInsetBottom();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        requestLayout();
    }

    public void setStatusBarBackground(Drawable bg) {
        mStatusBarBackground = bg;
        invalidate();
    }

    public Drawable getStatusBarBackgroundDrawable() {
        return mStatusBarBackground;
    }

    public void setStatusBarBackground(int resId) {
        mStatusBarBackground = resId != 0 ? ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), resId) : null;
        invalidate();
    }

    public void setStatusBarBackgroundColor(@ColorInt int color) {
        mStatusBarBackground = new ColorDrawable(color);
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        if (mDrawStatusBarBackground && mStatusBarBackground != null) {
            int inset = mLastInsets != null ? mLastInsets.getSystemWindowInsetTop() : 0;
            if (inset > 0) {
                mStatusBarBackground.setBounds(0, 0, getWidth(), inset);
                mStatusBarBackground.draw(canvas);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

main_activity.xml

```
<FitsSystemWindowConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/toolbar_background"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Content"
            android:textSize="48sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</FitsSystemWindowConstraintLayout>
```

Result :

[image: result]

Answer (score 1):

```
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

This will get you a transparent system bars until api 29.

From api 29+ you need to add

```
    <item name="android:enforceNavigationBarContrast">false</item>
```

this will stop the system from enforcing scrim color to ensure contrast ->
on the left enforceNavigationBarContrast=true, on the right equal to false.

[image: enforceNavigationBarContrast=true]
[image: enforceNavigationBarContrast=false]

using only xml you will have to create two theme files like this ->

right click on themes folder -> new -> values resource files
[image: step1]
[image: step2]
[image: result]

in order to make all of this to work these attributes must be false as stated [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr#statusBarColor), also if you just remove them from xml AND you are not setting the equivalent flags in code then they are turned off by default.

```
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">false</item>
```

also make sure that your view is full screen by setting

```
    WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
```

in onCreate

**Extra** 
sometimes you will need to change nav/status bar icons in case they blends with the background, in this case you have two options, light/dark icons, to change them you need to add

```
    <item name="android:windowLightNavigationBar">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
```

to do same changes i mentioned above but using code you will need these extensions functions

1. To change light status/nav bar

   ```
    fun Window.setLightStatusBar(state: Boolean) {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            insetsController?.setSystemBarsAppearance(
                /* appearance = */ if (state) 0 else APPEARANCE_LIGHT_STATUS_BARS,
                /* mask = */ APPEARANCE_LIGHT_STATUS_BARS
            )
        } else {
            decorView.systemUiVisibility = if (state) 0 else SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR
        }
    }

    fun Window.setLightNavigationBar(state: Boolean) {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            insetsController?.setSystemBarsAppearance(
                /* appearance = */ if (state) 0 else APPEARANCE_LIGHT_NAVIGATION_BARS,
                /* mask = */ APPEARANCE_LIGHT_NAVIGATION_BARS
            )
        } else {
            decorView.systemUiVisibility = if (state) 0 else SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_NAVIGATION_BAR
        }
    }
   ```
2. To set nav bar contrast

   ```
    fun Window.setNavigationBarContrastEnforcedIfSupported(enabled: Boolean) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            isNavigationBarContrastEnforced = enabled
        }
    }
   ```
3. to change colors to transparent

   ```
     window.setNavigationBarContrastEnforcedIfSupported(false)
     window.statusBarColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
     window.navigationBarColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
   ```

pay special attention that

1. calling setNavigationBarContrastEnforcedIfSupported must happen before setting nav bar color to transparent otherwise it will not take effect
2. if you are changing system bar light mode by code then you must remove any

   ```
    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowLightNavigationBar">true</item>
   ```

from xml otherwise it will not work, somehow when you use the deprecated `decorView.systemUiVisibility` -which is used by the xml attributes i guess- then when you try to mix its use with `insetsController?.setSystemBarsAppearance` they both stop to working properly, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68935230/6039240) for more info

also here is [a good article](https://marek-scholtz.medium.com/styling-system-bars-f27eb5196095) about system bars colors

Answer (score 0):

For those who want a completely transparent status bar and navigation bar on KitKat and up there is a small conflict with using `windowTranslucentNavigation` with @Machado answer's for Lollipop and to prevent that conflict separate the styles

styles.xml

```
<style name="LockScreenStyle" parent="@android:style/Theme.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus" tools:targetApi="kitkat">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation" tools:targetApi="kitkat">true</item>
</style>
```

styles.xml **(v21)**

```
<style name="LockScreenStyle" parent="@android:style/Theme.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
</style>
```

MyClass.java

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        Window w = getWindow(); // in Activity's onCreate() for instance
        w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            w.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also change the alpha of your colorPrimary and colorPrimaryDark to 00 and then add this to your onCreateMethod:

```
    window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
```

and also add this to your activity:

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is for the new guys like myself on Nativescript + Angular. I started off with one of  the blank templates on the [NTS marketplace](https://nativescript.org/blog/open-source-code-samples-in-the-nativescript-marketplace/). Then For my specific use, I need the status bar on top to be always transparent (similar to the iOS style) and the navbar (bottom) to be fully transparent (not translucent!) on some components/modules, while opaque in others. If everything is done according to the protocol set by NTS, you should have a main.ts (a prerequisite for my solution) similar to this
[image]

I separated my work into two pieces, top first, then the bottom. For the top I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58938185/how-can-i-change-the-statusbar-color-or-set-it-to-transparent-on-android-using) that worked. So you should have a main.ts file that looks like this.

```
import { platformNativeScriptDynamic } from "@nativescript/angular";

import { AppModule } from "./app/app.module";

import * as application from "tns-core-modules/application";
import { Color } from "@nativescript/core";

platformNativeScriptDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);

declare var android;

application.android.on(application.AndroidApplication.activityCreatedEvent, (event) => {

    const activity = event.activity;
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    activity.getWindow().addFlags(android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
    activity.getWindow().clearFlags(android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
    activity.getWindow().addFlags(android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);
    activity.getWindow().setStatusBarColor(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT);
    activity.getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT);

} else {
    activity.getWindow().addFlags(android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
    activity.getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT);
}

const parent = activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content);
for (let i = 0; i < parent.getChildCount(); i++) {
    const childView = parent.getChildAt(i);
    if (childView instanceof android.view.ViewGroup) {
        childView.setFitsSystemWindows(true);
        childView.setClipToPadding(true);
    }
}

});
```

Then to add transparency to the navbar, I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58938185/how-can-i-change-the-statusbar-color-or-set-it-to-transparent-on-android-using) and I add this to line 24 of the main.ts file above. `activity.getWindow().addFlags(android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);`

Now mind you there are also the styles.xml files we have to respect, so my styles.xml file (App_Resources\Android\src\main\res\values\styles.xml) looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<!-- theme to use FOR launch screen-->
<style name="LaunchScreenThemeBase" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/NativeScriptToolbarStyle</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/ns_primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/ns_primaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/ns_accent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/transparent</item>
</style>

<style name="LaunchScreenTheme" parent="LaunchScreenThemeBase"></style>

<!-- theme to use AFTER launch screen is loaded-->
<style name="AppThemeBase" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/NativeScriptToolbarStyle</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/ns_primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/ns_primaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/ns_accent</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/transparent</item>

    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">false</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppThemeBase"></style>

<!-- theme for action-bar -->
<style name="NativeScriptToolbarStyleBase" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="theme">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="popupTheme">@color/transparent</item>
</style>

<style name="NativeScriptToolbarStyle" parent="NativeScriptToolbarStyleBase"></style>
```

Took me about 2-3 days to figure out, hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

## From Android R

```
fun Activity.setTransparentStatusBar() {
    WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
    window.statusBarColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
    window.navigationBarColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
}
```

That's it

Answer (score 0):

Update: Just use `androidx.activity.enableEdgeToEdge()` instead

Outdated:

Based on [Arpan Sarkar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62483455) answer just made use of WindowCompat to reduce amount of code and avoid uses of deprecated definitions,

```
fun Activity.transparentSystemBars(
    behindStatusBarIsLight: Boolean,
    behindNavigationBarIsLight: Boolean,
) {
    // Android 4 is hard to debug and apparently ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener isn't
    // reporting any value there so let's skip and simplify
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) return

    WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)

    if (behindStatusBarIsLight || behindNavigationBarIsLight) {
        val insetsController: WindowInsetsControllerCompat =
            WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, window.decorView)
        if (behindStatusBarIsLight)
            insetsController.isAppearanceLightStatusBars = true
        if (behindNavigationBarIsLight)
            insetsController.isAppearanceLightNavigationBars = true
    }
    
    val isLightStatusBarAvailable = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M
    val isLightNavigationBarAvailable = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O
    val shouldStatusBarBeTransparent = !behindStatusBarIsLight || isLightStatusBarAvailable
    val shouldNavigationBarBeTransparent = !behindNavigationBarIsLight || isLightNavigationBarAvailable

    val systemUiScrim = ColorUtils.setAlphaComponent(Color.BLACK, 0x40) // 25% black
    window.statusBarColor = if (shouldStatusBarBeTransparent) Color.TRANSPARENT else systemUiScrim
    window.navigationBarColor = if (shouldNavigationBarBeTransparent) Color.TRANSPARENT else systemUiScrim

    // You may set android:enforceNavigationBarContrast to false in style.xml as doing it in code isn't as effective apparently.
}
```

There is also [EdgeToEdgeUtils.applyEdgeToEdge](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/1a91e68/lib/java/com/google/android/material/internal/EdgeToEdgeUtils.java) in the Material library which works but isn't supposed to be used by regular developers, guess it will be provided to the public someday.