# Wrong color in status bar

Tags: android, material-design

Why my status bar have this color? I need the same color as the toolbar (blue)

[image]

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="MFB" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

**settingsactivity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

In the main activity its working fine, look:

[image]

I dont know what is wrong here... i looked for an answer in other post but same i got the white status bar :/

Thank you :) and sorry if it is a noob question

**EDIT**

**Toolbar.xml:**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
```

**Note:** im using

```
"com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0" 
"com.android.support:design:23.4.0"
```

Comment: first of all specify what is your device version  and also post the `toolbar` layout file how you apply ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem must be you are not creating `res/values-v21 folder` to your project. to give different style to `Lollipop` and upper device you have to create `values-v21` folder in `res` directory and define your style there.

**styles.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/blue</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<style name="MFB" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
   <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

change above android:statusBarColor in your style.

```
   <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/blue</item>
```

it's working.I hope its solve your issue.

Comment: No, because when im in the navigation menu, the status bar is fully blue and should be transparent: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBhcd.png

Answer (score 1):

Try removing `<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>` thisline. Status bar takes color from `colorPrimaryDark`. Set this color to your desired one.

See this

[image]

**EDIT**

If you want to change the color of status bar at some stage in your app, you can try this

```
Window window = getWindow();
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
window.setStatusBarColor(YOUR_COLOR);
```

Comment: If i use
`Window window = getWindow();
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
window.setStatusBarColor(YOUR_COLOR);`
on settings activity _(color.transparent)_ it use the white background and no the color of toolbar. My app have theme engine (different colors to choose) and i need the status bar with the same color as the theme.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is set these properties in your theme:

true
true

Your activity / container layout you wish to have a transparent status bar needs this property set:

android:fitsSystemWindows=”true”

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            Window w = getWindow(); // in Activity's onCreate() for instance
            w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
        }
```

else go through this link would help you out

[completely transparent status bar and navigation bar on lollipop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29069070/completely-transparent-status-bar-and-navigation-bar-on-lollipop)

Hope it helps someone :).

Now I only need to make it backward compaitable.