# Gradient status bar with BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, android-layout, gradient, android-statusbar, android-bottom-nav-view

In my Application I want to show gradient status bar. Also i have used `BottomNavigationView`. So issue is when i am doing status bar gradient the bottom navigation bar of android overlaps the `BottomNavigationView`.

I have tried below solutions :

1. [how to set status bar background as gradient color or a drawable in android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43140039/8089770)
2. [Google Now gradient/shadow on status bar & navigation bar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40960687/8089770)
3. [How to apply gradient to status bar in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36907237/8089770)
4. [How to remove button bar at the bottom screen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19049764/8089770)

My code is as below :

-- > In java code i tried :

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            Window w = getWindow();
            w.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
            w.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);
        }
```

**Issue :: With this java code i have achieved status bar issue but bottom navigation bar of android overlaps the `BottomNavigationView`.**

-- > Also I have tried in style with :

```
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">false</item>
<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
```

**Issue :: But getting some dark color status bar by this code.**

-- > Also I have tried immersive mode of android :

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
                        // Set the content to appear under the system bars so that the
                        // content doesn't resize when the system bars hide and show.
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        // Hide the nav bar and status bar
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

**Issue :: But it hides the status bar and bottom navigation which i don't want to.**

******************* EDIT *******************

Tried in activity :

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        } else {

            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        }
```

In layout :

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
```

In style :

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">false</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">#000</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">#FFFFFF</item>
 </style>
```

*Any kind of help would be appreciable. Thank you !*

Comment: @NileshRathod I am getting white status bar instead of this with your given answer. I have diffrent layout for toolbar i have given fitSystemWindow true there and also added this in bottom navigation view activity. also set the transperent primary dark. still no luck. can you check

Comment: can u please edit your question with related code and expected output  so i can try to help you

Comment: @NileshRathod Please check edited question. My device is 6.0.1

Comment: and where is the image for expected output

Comment: Same as you have given in your answer it is expected one. and getting output as white status bar.. nav bar is perfect now.. can't post the image actually

Comment: Test case make `android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout` your rootlayout

Answer (score 3):

You above code is working fine for me

You need to change your root layout

Make **`CoordinatorLayout`** as your root layout

Use

**`android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout`**

Instead of

**`RelativeLayout`**

SEE the output using **`RelativeLayout`**

[image]

Output using **`android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout`**

[image]

Comment: still same issue in bottom navigation containing activity rest is okay. do i need to add this code in all fragment or a parent activity only? fitsystem window code

Comment: @Annie may be because i  have't tested this code in fragments

Comment: @Annie why asking new question don't do that

Comment: issue kya ave che m k mne nvo question puchi to koik duplicate mari deshe

Comment: To issue kya ave che

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181313/discussion-between-annie-and-nilesh-rathod).