# Background overlapsing notification bar while using custom toolbar with AppBarLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, toolbar, android-appbarlayout

I've created custom toolbar layout because I wanted to have a centered title on bar. The code looks like this:

main_activity.xml

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".mainactivity.MainActivity">

<!-- Appbar -->

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <!-- Toolbar -->

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mToolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    mTitle = mToolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
```

These gives me that:

[image]

But I want it to be like standard behavior:
[image]

I tried a lot of solution, like transparency styles for bar etc. Bo I cannot figure it out.

Could you help me?

Comment: You need to use `android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout` as your rootlayout  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52639958/gradient-status-bar-with-bottomnavigationview

Answer (score 1):

Using `ConstraintLayout` is not a good idea in there since maybe you'll need to hide or give the layout some effects later.

Instead, use `CoordinatorLayout` as the root of the layout and remove `ConstraintLayout` with it's attributes:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Appbar -->

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <!-- Toolbar -->

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/app_name"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**`AndroidX` (Newer versions):**

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Appbar -->

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <!-- Toolbar -->

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/app_name"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for so late answer, but I has something come around and I hadn't time to answer you.
If in my main `ConstraintLayout ` I also have an `include` view and `BottomNavigationView`, should I still be using `CoordinatorLayout`?

'Code':
`<CoordinatorLayout >


    <AppBarLayout>

        <Toolbar>
            <TextView/>
        </Toolbar>

    <AppBarLayout>


    <include
        />

    <BottomNavigationView
         />

</CoordinatorLayout>`

Comment: @Nilesh Rathod Could you look at that^ comment also?