# How to add a gradient in the navigationBar of the device in Android?

Tags: android, xml, flutter, dart

I have a Flutter app and I'm trying to add a gradient in the NaviagtionBottomBar of the app.
I've managed to add a singular color but I cant understand how to add a gradient.

This is my code and this is what the output

**styles.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    </style>
    <style name="NormalTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="android:windowLightNavigationBar">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**colors.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="blue">#87ceeb</color>
</resources>
```

Output: [image]

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/41001947/8257908

Answer (score 0):

In your dart code you can wrap `BottomNavigationBar` widget with Container and set `BoxDecoration` for decoration property of Container. then set gradient for `BoxDecoration`.

Comment: So this isn’t the bottomNav bar. It’s the Navigation Bar of the device.

Comment: Sorry. Now I understand what you say