# Transparent status bar not working perfectly

Tags: android, statusbar

I apologize to ask this question once because the previous solution couldn't address my problem.First I have set my style file with:

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
```

Then I included that style inside my activity in android manifest file.

After this is done I achieved my transparent status bar.But the activity details gone behind the actionbar. Then some one suggest me to put this code inside my parent view as

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

This changed my status bar to dark grey(not transparent).I got confused what to do?I just wish to change my status bar to transparent.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29311078/android-completely-transparent-status-bar and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29069070/completely-transparent-status-bar-and-navigation-bar-on-lollipop

Comment: This didnot worked for me sir

Answer (score 0):

From this post's answer. He has a solution to transparent stats/tool bar

[Android transparent status bar and actionbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29907615/android-transparent-status-bar-and-actionbar)