# How do I make the android home button bar transparent?

Tags: java, android

[image]

My app has a black bar over these home buttons and i need them to look transparent like below

[image]

Comment: This should help you. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29069070/completely-transparent-status-bar-and-navigation-bar-on-lollipop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29069070/completely-transparent-status-bar-and-navigation-bar-on-lollipop)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

set style to your main theme like below code

```
<resources>
    <style name="Theme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 2):

To do that inside of an App I used this into `styles.xml`

```
 <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
 <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
 <item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

set navigationBarColor to change color.

[Check here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#setNavigationBarColor(int)) to see flags required to mention. If color is opaque then there is different set of flags else another set of flags.

> void setNavigationBarColor (int color)
>   Blockquote
>
> Sets the color of the navigation bar to . For this to take effect, the
>   window must be drawing the system bar backgrounds with
>   FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS and FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION must
>   not be set. If is not opaque, consider setting
>   SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE and
>   SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION.
>
> The transitionName for the view background will be
>   "android:navigation:background".