# Fullscreen App With DisplayCutout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-9.0-pie

How do you make an app with an actual fullscreen capabilities, that has the layout to be rendered underneath the notch?

Here's what I want:

[image: Google Photos]

Here's the code of what I've tried:

```
class MainActivity : Activity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
//            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)

            val attrib = window.attributes
            attrib.layoutInDisplayCutoutMode = WindowManager.LayoutParams.LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_ALWAYS

            layout_main.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener { _, windowInsets ->
                val inset = windowInsets.displayCutout
                Log.d("Tag", "Inset: $inset")
                windowInsets
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/layout_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#3000FFFF"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <View
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#FFFF0000"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#FF00FF00"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#FF0000FF"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#FFFF00"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The style:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>

    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
</style>
```

Here's the Android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.app.testandroidp">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name="com.app.testandroidp.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here's the result that I've gotten so far:

[image]

I've tried setting different themes, setting the fullscreen flag in XML / Kotlin, setting the resizable activity in manifest, but the activity just won't get rendered under the notch.

For reference, this is the project's source code: https://gitlab.com/alvin.rusli/AndroidPTest

Comment: not sure where you got `window.attributes`, I had to use `getWindow().getAttributes()`.

Comment: @Michael Using Kotlin automatically removes the get/set from getter/setter methods

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I finally found out why. For some strange reason, the application won't enter the if condition:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
    // It never gets here
}
```

I removed that if condition and the activity finally goes fullscreen correctly.

[image: Activity underneath the notch]

---

Here are the bare minimum codes required to render the activity fullscreen.

Activity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // or add <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item> in the theme
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS)

        val attrib = window.attributes
        attrib.layoutInDisplayCutoutMode = WindowManager.LayoutParams.LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_SHORT_EDGES
    }
}
```

Styles:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <!-- Adding fullscreen will just hide the status bar -->
    <!-- <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item> -->
</style>
```

Comment: Yeah, the version code returned by the emulator is still 27. Lint gives you incorrect fixes, you basically have to @SuppressLint("NewAPI") everywhere...

Comment: I think `LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_ALWAYS` was replaced with `LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_SHORT_EDGES` : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams#LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_SHORT_EDGES . Is it true? Is it the same meaning? That it will take entire screen, including the unsafe areas?

Comment: @androiddeveloper I tested updating the code, and changing the ALWAYS to the new SHORT_EDGES work just like before, but now I wonder what you have to do to make a complete fullscreen view for that "double cutout" notches

Comment: @AlvinRusli For that, you can have 2 options: immersive mode, as shown here: https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive . Or, if you want to show the navigation bar, use this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29138275/878126 , including this in code: `window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS)`

Comment: @androiddeveloper Got it, `window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION` works, thanks!

Comment: I think `MODE_SHORT_EDGES` will always behave just like `MODE_ALWAYS` because for now cutouts are only permitted on short edges of devices. From the documentation of DisplayCutout.getBoundingRects "There will be at most one non-functional area per short edge of the device, and none on the long edges.". Clearly by renaming `MODE_ALWAYS`, google are leaving the door open for notches to start appearing on long edges in future API revisions, but for now we're safe.

Comment: Is there no XML equivalent to `attrib.layoutInDisplayCutoutMode = WindowManager.LayoutParams.LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_ALWAYS`?

Comment: This won't work if we are supporting minimum API <28 so we can't remove the if condition. How else will the app know whether to use the condition or not?

Comment: @AlvinRusli How about in landscape mode, is it fixed?

Answer (score 54):

Set these properties in your theme :

```
<item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">shortEdges</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
```

Comment: I had the same issue on a Pixel 5A device and this was the only way to achieve the "real" immersive fullscreen mode.

Comment: This makes full screen keyboard background transparent !! how to fix that ?

Answer (score 25):

I tried lot's of things but didn't get any success, then I try the following code and it's working fine.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
            getWindow().getAttributes().layoutInDisplayCutoutMode = WindowManager.LayoutParams.LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_SHORT_EDGES;
        }

      ---
    }
```

I hope it's helpful.

Answer (score 16):

if nothing works then try this one once

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P){
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
    }
```

Comment: This is the only answer which is working on notch devices.

Comment: perfect solution with condition...:)

Answer (score 9):

I`m having same problem while developing App for Notch Device, i cater this issue by defining the theme style for android P devices and set the mode like default,shortEdges,never mode.

**Step 1:**
Create a new values-v28 folder in your res directory and copy the default styles.xml file into it.

**Step 2:**
In the values-28 variant of the styles.xml file, go to your Activity’s theme or create a new one if you’ve been using the default one, and set this attribute:

```
<style name="ActivityTheme">
  <item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">
    shortEdges
  </item>
</style>
```

That’s all you have to do to get a more immersive experience in your app and avoid letterboxing by making the app’s window render on either side areas of the notch.

[image]

> Here is the link to learn more about Developing Compatible App for Notch Devices.
>   [Making Notch Friendly Apps](https://proandroiddev.com/making-notch-friendly-apps-for-android-75776272be5c)

Comment: worked like a charm

Answer (score 9):

This is what worked for me:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
        getWindow().getAttributes().layoutInDisplayCutoutMode = WindowManager.LayoutParams.LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_SHORT_EDGES;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

below code worked for me, I hope it works for you too:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);//will hide the title
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); //show the activity in full screen
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pdf_view);

    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
        getWindow().getAttributes().layoutInDisplayCutoutMode = WindowManager.LayoutParams.LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_SHORT_EDGES;
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to apply it everywhere in your app then there is a simpler solution according to Android Documentation:

Add this item in your theme file(s)

```
  <item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">
    shortEdges <!-- default, shortEdges, or never -->
  </item>
```

[See more at this Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/display-cutout)

Answer (score 1):

That is because you were using Android P when it wasn't officially released yet.

You probably have a Developer Preview that has some issues with the vendor. If you search Google for your system and find an XDA page, you may be able to see "Vendor" listed among the bugs of your ROM.

Usually, Developer Previews keep the vendor of the previous Android version, which means your app thinks to be in Android Oreo, when you're checking for it in the following line:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following style ,

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: That's strange, can you please post the code of your manifest.xml ?

Comment: Sure, it's a completely blank project and has nothing in it though, I'll just post the gitlab link on the question.

Comment: @AlvinRusli, sorry, but I too wasn't able to solve it.