# How can I make my Android app full screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-theme

This is my style.xml

```xml
<resources>
    <style name="AppDefaultTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

If I set the fullscreen parameter, the status bar will turn into an ugly black border.

Can I achieve a full screen without the help of appcompat? Or hide the status bar icon?

[img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1adop.jpg)

[image: img2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried for a long time yesterday to understand the need to add this property.

```xml
<item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode"tools:ignore="NewApi">shortEdges</item>
```

For applications that do not use appcompat, an immersive status bar should also be added.

```xml
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your activity code, you can retrieve the top-level window decor view of the current window and request that the visibility of the status bar or other screen/window decorations be changed.

You can try with multiple flags like this and experiment accordingly.

Example (java):

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
```

Comment: <item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode" tools:ignore="NewApi">shortEdges</item>

I tried for a long time yesterday to understand the need to add this property.

Comment: Please take a look at this as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49190381/fullscreen-app-with-displaycutout