# How to have transparent navigation bar while having views above it and behind it?

Tags: android, android-navigation-bar

### Background

It's possible to have the navigation bar to be transparent, so that content  will be drawn behind it (in Z coordinate) and that there will be views above it (in Y coordinate), like on the camera app:

[image]

For the Camera app, there is content behind the navigation bar (the camera preview), and there are views above it (the buttons)

### The problem

Every solution I've found (and there are many, such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29069070/878126)) doesn't let me the choice of having both transparent navigation bar while having views above it and behind it.

### What I've tried

Here's one way I tried to solve it, using `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` (sample [here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=04899772774562321383)):

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
            window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="#33ff0000"
              android:text="text behind nav bar"
              app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
              app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="#3300ff00"
              android:text="text above nav bar" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
              app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
              app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

But the result is that both views are behind the navigation bar :

[image]

The only way I've found that works, is to get the height of the navigation bar, and set the bottom margin of the view to be with this value, but this seems like a weird solution, which I'd like to try to avoid :

```
/**
 * returns the natural orientation of the device: Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE or Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT .<br></br>
 * The result should be consistent no matter the orientation of the device
 */
fun getScreenNaturalOrientation(context: Context): Int {
    with(context) {
        //based on : http://stackoverflow.com/a/9888357/878126
        val windowManager = getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager
        val config = resources.configuration
        val rotation = windowManager.defaultDisplay.rotation
        return if ((rotation == Surface.ROTATION_0 || rotation == Surface.ROTATION_180) && config.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE || (rotation == Surface.ROTATION_90 || rotation == Surface.ROTATION_270) && config.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
            Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
        else
            Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT
    }
}

fun getNavBarHeight(context: Context, defaultHeightToReturn: Int = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 48f, context.resources.displayMetrics).toInt()): Int {
    val resources = context.resources
    val orientation = resources.configuration.orientation
    val isTablet = getScreenNaturalOrientation(context) == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
    val resourceId = if (isTablet)
        resources.getIdentifier(if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) "navigation_bar_height" else "navigation_bar_height_landscape", "dimen", "android")
    else
        resources.getIdentifier(if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) "navigation_bar_height" else "navigation_bar_width", "dimen", "android")
    if (resourceId > 0) {
        return resources.getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId)
    }
    return defaultHeightToReturn
}
```

### The questions

1. How come it ignores `android:fitsSystemWindows` ?
2. How can I make one view above the navigation bar and one behind it, like on the camera app ? I also don't want that on old Android versions there will be extra space for no reason.

---

EDIT: about why `android:fitsSystemWindows` doesn't work, I've found this and this. However, when I tried to use this technique by just having a `CoordinatorLayout`, it still didn't work on the above case:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                                 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                                 tools:context=".MainActivity" android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                 android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="#33ff0000"
              android:text="text behind nav bar" android:textSize="20sp" android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    />

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textSize="20sp" android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="#3300ff00"
              android:text="text above nav bar" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Just to clarify, by *"above the navigation bar"*, do you mean directly obscuring the back/home/window controls? Or just at a greater z-index but not directly covering?

Comment: "above" is in the Y coordinate. "behind" is in the Z coordinate. Will update the question to make it clear.

Answer (score -1):

You can make the background of the navigation bar same as the background of your activity that would make it appear as a transparent.

Comment: I don't want a color for it. I want to have it transparent, and also be able to have a view behind it and above it.

Comment: The Camera app doesn't have just a color for the navigation bar. It shows a preview of the video behind it.

Answer (score -1):

In order to do that you need to

set view Background property to null or Color.TRANSPARENT

of setAlpha of Color as like 0x00FFFFFF

and apply to the background like view.setBackground(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

Comment: Of what? And how could this help with the position of the views, if that's only about colors?