# How to make flutter app draw behind android navigation bar and make navigation bar fully transparent?

Tags: flutter, dart, uinavigationbar, flutter-layout, transparent

I would like to make my Flutter app take up the entire screen in Android while still showing both the status bar and the navigation bar, with both of them transparent, to achieve the full screen look like in [iOS](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/first-flutter-app-pt1/img/6556f8b61acd6a89.gif).

The status bar color can be easily changed, but right now I'm facing problems with getting the app to fill up the screen and making the navigation bar transparent at the same time.

By default, the app is not drawn below the navigation bar at all (I've set the status bar color to be transparent):

[image: default app without modifications]

Here are some solutions I've tried:

#### 1) Setting flags on window in the onCreate function in MainActivity

Solution taken from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31596735

```java
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
  window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, 
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS)
}
```

This sort of achieves what I want, but it has several problems. The padding and inset values in `MediaQuery` are now 0, so I have to manually get the status bar and nav bar heights through the use of `MethodChannel`. Furthermore, this creates a weird bug regarding the application switcher, as shown below (see how the content jumps and the debug banner on the top right is stretched):

[image: solution 1 bug]

#### 2) Adding translucent navigation in styles.xml

```xml
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
```

Result:

[image: solution 2 result]

This is the closest to what I want to achieve. `MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top` correctly shows the top padding, and `MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom` correctly shows the height of the navbar. There are no weird bugs in the application switcher as well. The only problem is that the navbar is translucent and not transparent.

Here's the repo for the sample app shown above: https://github.com/CZX123/navbar

It would be nice if Flutter could provide this functionality out of the box. But it doesn't, so are there any other better ways to achieve this?

### Update

It seems like we would have to wait for the Flutter team to officially implement this feature:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/40974
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/34678

This comment also perfectly sums up the current behavior in Android: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/34678#issuecomment-536028077

Comment: No, this is not what this about. This issue is about the actual system UI navigation (as introduced in Android Q) not rendering properly in Flutter.

Comment: Did you find any solution to make the system navigation bar transparent?

Answer (score 24):

After **Flutter 2.5.0**:

This works for me like charm!

Inside your `main()` paste the code below:

```
//Setting SysemUIOverlay
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
    systemStatusBarContrastEnforced: true,
    systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.transparent,
    systemNavigationBarDividerColor: Colors.transparent,
    systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
    statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark)
);
    
//Setting SystmeUIMode
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.edgeToEdge, overlays: [SystemUiOverlay.top]);
```

Answer (score 8):

There is a simple way to get around this using flutter natively on android SDK 29 and later without having to edit any other source file.

##### spoiler : instead of `Colors.transparent` use any color with `0.002` Opacity.

firstly you need to set the `SystemUiMode` to fullscreen display with status and navigation elements rendered over the application.

```dart
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.edgeToEdge);
```

Then set the color of the navigation bar in `setSystemUIOverlayStyle` to any color with opacity of `0.002` (It's the minimum value you can use)

```dart
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
    SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.002),
    ),
  );
```

the result :
[image]

If you focus too hard, you may notice a slight color difference, however you can go further and set the navigation bar color to the background color and you won't notice any difference.

I use a global function to set it when changing the app theme

```dart
void setSystemUIOverlayStyle(final Color color) {
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
    SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      systemNavigationBarColor: color.withOpacity(0.002),
    ),
  );
}
```

I don't know what is the issue with the transparent color but if the color is nearly transparent then everything will work fine.

Comment: This really works!!! Tks

Comment: it will glith if you wanna use dialog... we need the dialog overlay are covered entire screen

Comment: @Umar
No, it works as expected with dialog/overlay, just don't use `SafeArea`

Comment: aggre, tested for now, thanks brother

Comment: btw i just leaved flutter for now cause laggy, janky animation issue, i switched to native with jetpack compose

Answer (score 3):

I achieved the transparency effect throughout my app easily by editing the following files

1.Add the following lines in **android/app/build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.5.0-beta01' //add this line
}
```

2.Add the following in your **android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/*<your_domain>*/*<your_project_name>*/MainActivity.kt**

```
import androidx.core.view.WindowCompat //add this line
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
    //add the following block of code
    override fun onPostResume() {
        super.onPostResume()
        WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
        window.navigationBarColor = 0 //for transparent nav bar
        window.statusBarColor = 0 //for transparent status bar
    }
}
```

3. Remove SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle commands from your main.dart
4. Run `flutter clean` and re run your app.

***NOTE:***

- In case you nest a stack direct under the scaffold for some screen,
  you might see your app drawing above nav bar. To fix that just set
  the following property on scaffold

  `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false`
- If you use an appbar or safeArea you might need to override the SystemUIOverlayStyle again using **AnnotatedRegion**

Answer (score 2):

Though I don't know, which side effects this approach might cause, I believe it offers a solution to your question:

```dart
Scaffold(
  primary: false,
  appBar: AppBar(
    primary: false,
    // ...
  ),
  // ...
)
```

Setting both the Scaffold's and the AppBar's primary property to `false` removes their inner SafeArea, which renders them behind system UI.

Answer (score 2):

The following worked for me:

**build.gradle (app)**

```
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.5.0-rc01'
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {

    override fun onPostResume() {
        super.onPostResume()
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
            window.navigationBarColor = 0
        }
    }
}
```

**main.dart**

```
void main() {
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark.copyWith(
    systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.transparent,
    statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
  ));
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Inspiration came from https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/40974

Comment: Updating build.gradle and MainActivity worked for me.

Comment: error FlutterError (No MaterialLocalizations found. on i added dialog

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have been using on my main screen widget:

1 - To extend the app area over the navigation bar

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.manual, overlays: [SystemUiOverlay.top]);
  }
```

2 - To make both the status and navigation bars transparent according to the current theme brightness:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Brightness currentBrightness = Theme.of(context).brightness;
    Brightness oppositeBrightness = currentBrightness == Brightness.light ? Brightness.dark : Brightness.light;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle(
          statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
          statusBarBrightness: currentBrightness,
          statusBarIconBrightness: oppositeBrightness,
          systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.transparent,
          systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: oppositeBrightness,
        ),
        /* ... */
      ),
      /* ... */
    );
  }
```

Comment: does it from 1 to 2 or choose one?

Answer (score 0):

as last flutter 3.19.x

your code main activity its worked for me and the MediaQuery have excact value not 0, tested in android 14

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
  window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, 
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just enable edge to edge screen

```
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.edgeToEdge); // Enable Edge-to-Edge on Android 10+
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.transparent, // Setting a transparent navigation bar color
    ));
```

Answer (score -1):

So if you are using Flutter the procedure is:

1. Set `AppBar()` color to transparent.
2. Set `extendBeyondAppBar` to `true`.
3. Set `elevation` to 0.

As an example:

```js
    return Scaffold(
        extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
        appBar: AppBar(
           elevation: 0,
           )
```

Comment: This is not about the navigation bar.

Comment: This is not the correct answer. This is about the modern Android behavior where a small gesture navigation bar is drawn *over* the app.

Answer (score -4):

```
return Scaffold(
   body: AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
    value: SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
      systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.transparent
    ),
    sized: false,
    child: Container(color: Colors.red)
  )
);
```

Answer (score -4):

This might be late, but the latest version for flutter, 1.12 provides a feature to draw the app behind the NavigationBar, so the following code will have the transparent navigation bar with app fully extended behind the navigation bar,

```
Scaffold(
  extendBodyBehindAppBar: true, //this ensures that the body is drawn behind the navigation bar as well
  appBar: AppBar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    title: Text('Transparent Bar'),
  ),
  body: Container(
    color: Colors.blue,
  ),
);
```

Comment: only works for AppBar, doesn't extend behind system navigation

Answer (score -4):

Have you tried the below method

```
// to hide only bottom bar:
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays ([SystemUiOverlay.top]);

// to hide only status bar: 
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays ([SystemUiOverlay.bottom]);

// to hide both:
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays ([]);
```

Comment: I do not want to hide the app bar, I want to make their background transparent.