# How to make the navigation bar translucent and make the layout display under it

Tags: android, navigation, translucency

I want to make the navigation bar translucent. I am able to do that. But the layout of my fragment is not visible under the translucent navigation bar. My textViews becarme completely white and proper translucency is not achieved. I have read the android documentations, used many flags but I am not able to achieve the transparency as I expect. Please help me.

Here is my Fragment Layout code.

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
tools:context=".fragments.ExpenseFragment">
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    tools:context=".fragments.ExpenseFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/monthly_amount_tv"
            android:layout_width="244dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/borders_and_lines"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/monthlyAmount"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/monthly_amount_tv2"
            android:layout_width="117dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="-1dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-1dp"
            android:background="@drawable/no_border_left"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="11dp"
            android:text="0"
            android:textColor="@color/batteryChargedBlue"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

        android:layout_width="386dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/increase_tv"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="87dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="Increase Monthly Amount ?"
            android:textColor="@color/batteryChargedBlue"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="italic" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/refresh"
            android:layout_width="22dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_refresh_black_24dp" />


    </LinearLayout>


    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:background="@color/greenBlue" />


<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycle_view"
    android:layout_width="387dp"
    android:layout_height="459dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/total_amount_tv"
            android:layout_width="174dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-1dp"
            android:background="@drawable/no_border_bottom"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/totalExpenses"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/total_amount_tv2"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-3dp"
            android:background="@drawable/no_border_left"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:text="0"
            android:textColor="@color/batteryChargedBlue"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_note_add_black_24dp"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/batteryChargedBlue"
            app:fabCustomSize="49dp"
            app:maxImageSize="30dp" />


    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"

        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/remaining_amount_tv"
            android:layout_width="236dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@drawable/borders_and_lines"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/remainingAmount"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/remaining_amount_tv2"
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="-1dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-1dp"
            android:background="@drawable/no_border_left"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="11dp"
            android:text="0"
            android:textColor="@color/batteryChargedBlue"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [completely transparent status bar and navigation bar on lollipop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29069070/completely-transparent-status-bar-and-navigation-bar-on-lollipop)

Comment: Problem still exists!!! @NikosHidalgo