# How can i change the StatusBar color or set it to transparent on Android, using NativeScript with Angular?

Tags: android, angular, nativescript, statusbar, transparent

I'm using NativeScript with Angular, and I can't seem to change the StatusBar color in my project or set it to transparent (any of these would be fine). Instead, it is not totally transparent, but is translucent black, so the background scrolls behind it but it is darkened by the StatusBar. I would like to set it to transparent or to change the color (to the same one as the page background)

**What I've tried:**

- Changing the "**ns_primaryDark**" and "**ns_primary**" colors in **App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/values/colors.xml** (works on launch screen if i set the **TranslucentStatus**" to **false**;
- Setting `<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus"></item>` in `<style name="AppThemeBase" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">`  in **App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/values/styles.xml** doesn't make any difference, despite working fine on `<style name="LaunchScreenThemeBase" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">` (the launch screen);
- Setting `<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>` changes the text color to black and works on both the launch screen and the main app;
- Using the code below in any component's constructor doesn't change anything in my app, but it worked on the other project i tried (details below), setting the color to black:

```
let window = app.android.startActivity.getWindow();
window.setStatusBarColor(new Color("black").android);
```

One thing i also tried was doing these steps on another project i had downloaded (https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-ui-samples/tree/master/chart this one, to be exact) and **it worked**, so i thought the template i used in my application might be "overlaying" any settings for the StatusBar.

I then tried to make a new project with the same template as mine and i figured out that **it didn't work** either. Is the template my problem? If so, is there any way to get around it?

The template i used is this one: https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-app-templates/tree/master/packages/template-tab-navigation-ng (also works with "**tns create my-app-name --template tns-template-tab-navigation-ng**").

Big thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following code to your `main.ts`, that should do the job.

```
import * as application from "tns-core-modules/application";

declare var android;

application.android.on(application.AndroidApplication.activityCreatedEvent, (event) => {

    const activity = event.activity;

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        activity.getWindow().addFlags(android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        activity.getWindow().clearFlags(android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        activity.getWindow().addFlags(android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);
        activity.getWindow().setStatusBarColor(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT);
    } else {
        activity.getWindow().addFlags(android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
    }

    const parent = activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    for (let i = 0; i < parent.getChildCount(); i++) {
        const childView = parent.getChildAt(i);
        if (childView instanceof android.view.ViewGroup) {
            childView.setFitsSystemWindows(true);
            childView.setClipToPadding(true);
        }
    }
});
```

It's pretty much as in the library. If you like to use the library, you will have to include it in your app grad and access the StatusBarUtil class.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been struggling with this for so long and it finally worked! I wasn't able to get the library to work, maybe i was doing something wrong. Either way, your code did the trick!

Comment: One thing i noticed was that the navigation bar (the bottom one) turns translucent and the background goes behind it. I tried deleting the flag "TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION" but it turns the status bar white if i do that. Is there anyway to change just the status bar? Thanks.

Comment: You can check the images in the other answer. That's how it looks, I'm not sure if you can make only status bar transparent. Will check.

Comment: Removing the line `activity.getWindow().addFlags(android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);` seems to do the job on my end, navigation bar was not transparent anymore. Tested on Android 8.1, a Motorola device.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this library to transparent your status bar [Library](https://github.com/laobie/StatusBarUtil)

> compile 'com.jaeger.statusbarutil:library:1.4.0'

To make any specific activity to transparent you can simply use this

> StatusBarUtil.setTransparent(Activity activity)

It will look like this

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! I'm still trying to figure out how to install the library. I'll keep trying.

Comment: its so simple just add compile 'com.jaeger.statusbarutil:library:1.4.0' in your dependency and sync then do your task