# Android API level 30 setSystemBarsAppearance doesn't overwrite theme data

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles, android-11, windowinsets

Pre-Android 11 (API Level 30) I had
`<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>`
set in my theme and was additionally changing this (when needed) in the the code with

```
fun setLightStatusBar(){ 
    window?.decorView?.let { it.systemUiVisibility = it.systemUiVisibility or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR }
} 

fun setDarkStatusBar(){
    window?.decorView?.let { it.systemUiVisibility = it.systemUiVisibility and View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR.inv() }
}
```

However, Android-30 adds a new way to control with

```
fun setLightStatusBar(){ 
    window?.insetsController?.setSystemBarsAppearance(APPEARANCE_LIGHT_STATUS_BARS, APPEARANCE_LIGHT_STATUS_BARS)
} 

fun setDarkStatusBar(){
    window?.insetsController?.setSystemBarsAppearance(0, APPEARANCE_LIGHT_STATUS_BARS)
}
```

but my issue is that this cannot overwrite the theme-set values and thus I need to either do it all with styles or all in code.

**My question is if this is intended to be like this or am I missing something somewhere?**

Comment: Crazy droid. Also does not work, I just use the deprecated API and everything works (no other choice) ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Just checked and it works for api 31 but not for api 30

Answer (score 3):

I removed `<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true/false</item>` from `styles.xml` and it worked correctly.

Comment: Does not work for me, the flag is not cleared to dark status bar

Answer (score 3):

If you set `android:windowLightStatusBar` to `true` in your theme, you need to do the deprecated call, which removes the system UI flag, to make it work.

```
activity.window.decorView.run {
    systemUiVisibility =
        systemUiVisibility and View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR.inv()
}
```

It seems like both `WindowInsetsController` and `systemUiVisibility` both controls the status bar theme, but in different mechanisms.