# How to full screen activity with transparent status bar?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-statusbar

I would like to show transparent status bar without using immersive mode. Just like the image below. I have tried lot of solutions however I'm unable to achieve this. Please refer the image below.

[image]

This is the output I'm looking for. Please note here that I'm looking for solution which doesn't affect navigation bar at all. I don't want any modifications to navigation bar just like image below.
Thanks in advance!

My theme:

```xml
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar.Bridge">
<item name="android:colorEdgeEffect">@color/color_subtitle_text</item>
<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
```

Comment: i think you looking like following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29069070/completely-transparent-status-bar-and-navigation-bar-on-lollipop

Comment: Thanks for the link however I'm unable to achieve full screen with transparent status bar with this link. It only shows how we can achieve transparent status bar. Right now I'm unable to draw anything on status bar. it is always dark color. Im using
@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar.Bridge
theme

Comment: you can extend that theme and add extra things into that

Comment: Im adding more info on what I have done with theme.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```java
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
```

Comment: This is not working. This will make navigation bar transparent. I only need statusbar as transparent.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this.

For `Kotlin`:

```kotlin
window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS)
```

For `Java`:

```java
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
```

Comment: This will make navigation bar disappear. This is not what I'm looking for.